# How can I receive media from users in DialogFlow?

Tags: dialogflow-es

I want to receive an image from the user and handle it with a webhook but there is no MEDIA event. Is there any way I can do it?

A possible solution would be to skip DialogFlow interaction depending on some context, but I have not been able to do this either. If I add an input context to an intent without any training phrase and with high priority, the intent is never executed. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: can you tell on which platform you want to handle media?

Comment: Facebook Messenger